# Looping through repeater items

Tags: c#, repeater

I have a repeater which is built like the following:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems" OnItemDataBound="rptItems_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="span12 grey-box">
                        <div class="hero-block3">
                            <div class="row show-grid">
                                <div class="span9">
                                    <div class="hero-content-3">
                                        <h2><asp:Literal ID="ltrName" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h2>
                                        <p><asp:Literal ID="ltrDescription" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span3">
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlAmount" runat="server">
                                    <div class="tour-btn" id="divAmount" runat="server">
                                        <small>How Many?<br /></small>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbox" Width="40"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear-both"></div>
                    <br />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

It's bound using:

```
  ListProducts = db.GetDataTable("select * from Products where Id in (" + selectedValues + ")");

        rptItems.DataSource = ListProducts;
        rptItems.DataBind();
```

And then extra stuff is done with:

```
protected void rptItems_ItemDataBound(object sender,
                                  System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView nRow = null;

        switch (e.Item.ItemType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Item:
            case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                nRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
                ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrDescription")).Text = "" + nRow["Description"];
                ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrName")).Text = "" + nRow["Name"];

                if ("" + nRow["HasAmount"] == "False")
                {
                    ((Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlAmount")).Visible = false;
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

However, now on an onclick event for the page, i'm trying to save the information stored - This is what i've done so far, but it always all seems to be null, and I can't add a .text etc to the end of the `(TextBox)item.FindControl("tbSelected");`

Heres my loop i'm trying on click:

```
protected void doStageThree(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptItems.Items)
            {
                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    var tbSelected = (TextBox)item.FindControl("tbSelected");
                    var lblDescription = (Literal)item.FindControl("ltrDescription");
                    var lblName = (Literal)item.FindControl("ltrName");

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try "foreach (Control c in rptItemss.Items)" instead of RepeaterItems, then   ((TextBox)c.FindControl("tbSelected")).Text

Comment: That looks like it could work, how would I protect if (TextBox)c.FindControl("tbSelected") is null (it's now always shown)

Comment: var text = (c.FindControl("tbSelected")== null ? "Empty" : ((TextBox)c.FindControl("tbSelected")).Text; 
Play around with the debugger and see what works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always null because there is no `TextBox` with id `tbSelected`

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbox" Width="40"></asp:TextBox>
```

change it to:

```
var tbSelected = (TextBox)item.FindControl("tbox");
```

To protect your code from null use keyword `as`:

```
var tbSelected = item.FindControl("tbox") as TextBox;

if (tbSelected != null)
{
   //textbox with id tbox exists
   tbSelected.Text = "your text";
}
```

Comment: However, saying that - tbselected always = ""

Comment: Check if you are not rebinding your repeater inside `Page_Load` after `PostBack` event as it will clear all values, happens very often :)

Comment: What if I have more than one textboxes (maybe 10) and I want to add certain textboxes to a list?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptItems.Items)
```

with

```
    foreach (Control c in rptItems.Items)
    {
        if(c.FindControl("tbSelected") != null)
        {
           var selectedText = ((TextBox)c.FindControl("tbSelected")).Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah and as gzaxx pointed out there is no next box called tbSelected, it's called tBox in your sample code, it should have a more descriptive name like tbHowManyItems