# Pass value from a Repeater row to a textbox on button click in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I have the following repeater wrapped in an Update Panel

```
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
             <Triggers>
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
             </Triggers>
             <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="skillTable" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ID="skillButton" OnClick="skillButton_Click" CommandArgument="<%# Eval(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)%>" class="addText btn btn-success" ImageUrl="~/img/addbut.png" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" id="skillName" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, DropDownList1.SelectedValue) %>'></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It kicks out the information from my database perfectly, and it has a button right before the text in each row.

The problem that i have is that I need each button on each row to, when clicked, add the specific line of code in that row to a textbox.

```
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in skillTable.Items)
    {
        string skill = item.DataItem.ToString();
        string text = skillList.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {

            if (!text.Contains(skill))
            {
                text += "  |  " + skill;
                skillList.Text = text;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            text = skill;
            skillList.Text = text;
        }
    }
    UpdatePanel2.Update();
```

I have also tried this way,

```
     protected void skillTable_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    int d = 0;
        if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Business and Finance")
        {
            d = 1;
        }
        else if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Computers and Technology")
        {
            d = 2;
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Education")
        {
            d = 3;
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Customer Service")
        {
            d = 4;
        }
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        string skill = drv[d].ToString();
        Session["Table"] = skill;

}
protected void skillButton_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string skill = (string)(Session["Table"]);
    string text = skillList.Text;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {

        if (!text.Contains(skill))
        {
            text += "  |  " + skill;
            skillList.Text = text;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        text = skill;
        skillList.Text = text;
    }
    UpdatePanel2.Update();
}
```

but neither one of them seems to work correctly. Any advice? I havent really used repeaters before this, so If there is any other tool that would work better, I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps this link may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606208/looping-through-repeater-items

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, I've tried that link, however, that returns everything in the repeater table. I just want one specific row to be pulled when you click on that specific row's button. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. What I was missing was a way for my site to specifically narrow down what i needed. I added the code blow to my click method and got rid of the ItemDataBound method and it worked like a charm.

```
    Button button = (sender as Button);
    string commandArgument = button.CommandArgument;
    RepeaterItem item = button.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
    var workText = (Label)item.FindControl("workName1") as Label;
    string work = workText.Text;
    string text = workDetails1.Text;
    if (text == "   ")
        text = "";

    if (text == "")
    {
        if (!text.Contains(work))
        {
            text +="\u2022 " + work;
            workDetails1.Text = text;
        }
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(work))
    {
        if (!text.Contains(work))
        {
            text += "\n\u2022 " + work;
            workDetails1.Text = text;
        }
        else
        {
            workDetails1.Text = text;
        }
    }
    UpdatePanel4.Update();
```

Hope this helps someone!